# How do I implement a nested structure in gdscript?

Tags: struct, nested, gdscript

I found this question on how to make a structure: [How do I implement structures in GDScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56022622/how-do-i-implement-structures-in-gdscript)

I tried using the suggestions to make a nested structure, but couldn't figure out how.

The following dictionary way doesn't work:

```
# doesn't work
var stuct = {
  foo = 1
  nested = {
    bar = 2
  }
}
```

Nor does the following class way:

```
# doesn't work
class struct:
    static var foo: Number
    class inner:
        static var bar: Number
```

If I don't define the type of `foo` in the class way, then I can get it to work.  But I would like to have all my types set up.  I also do not have values for all variables in my real world case, some need to be set by external operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries are comma separated:

```
var stuct = {
    foo = 1, # <- Notice the comma
    nested = {
        bar = 2
    }
}
```

---

About the class, I don't know what the type `Number` you are using is. And for what you say, I'm guessing neither does Godot. However, if it is defined and in scope then it should work.

Be aware that defining your classes with `class` does not put them in the global scope. See [Using a custom class in Godot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67871175/402022).

Aside from that, have a look at the list of [build-in types in GDScript](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/getting_started/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html#built-in-types). *Perhaps `int` or `float` would do?*